# Java How to produce generic class that accepts a String and integer?

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm trying to get familiar with generics in java. I'm still unsure how create a simple class to take two types (String, Integer). Below is a trivial attempt at working with generics in my contexts.

```
public class Container <T>
{

  public T aString()
  {
     //Do i know I have a string?
  }

  public T anInt()
  {
    //How do I know I have an integer?
  }

  public Container<T>()
  {
    //What would the constructor look like?
  }


}
```

I'm referencing this page [oracle generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) but I'm still not sure what I'm doing here. Do you first figure out what type your "T" in the class?

Is generic programming genuinely used for interfaces and abstract classes?

Comment: Trying to constrain the type of objects in your generic collection to two classes (String and Integer) which do not have a common ancestor short of Object seems a bit forced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that Container class can actually hold a String, Integer or any type, you just have to use it correctly. Something like this:

```
public class Container<T> {
    private T element;

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Container(T someElement) {
        this.element = someElement;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Container<Integer> myIntContainer = new Container<Integer>();
myIntContainer.setElement(234);
```

or...

```
Container<String> myStringContainer = new Container<String>();
myStringContainer.setElement("TEST");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is more less what I wanted to see/hear. But what about the constructor? What would that look like?

Comment: You could just pass an argument of type T to your constructor.  I'll edit this answer to add an example...

Answer (score 2):

If the class does significantly different things for String and Integer, maybe it should be two classes, each specialized for one of those types.

I see generics as being useful for situations in which references of different types can be handled the same way. `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` don't need any code that is specific to String or Integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class type = Integer.class
Integer i = verifyType("100",type);
```

for integer, similar with string...

reference [Java Generics with Class <T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932090/java-generics-with-class-t)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `String` and `Integer` you'll probably have to use `Object` as the type. This removes most of the benefit of Generics frankly and you should probably check that you actually have a sound model and reason for inter-weaving strings and integers.

But yes, it's useful for interfaces, custom classes and abstracts. It means you can guarantee the object is of the right type and removes the need to implement them each time for each type of thing.