# No ClassCastException when casting to generic type different to actual class

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I have some code which looks something like this (part of a negative test of the method `get`):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main (String ... args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.put("test", "value"); // Store a String
        System.out.println("Test: " + test.get("test", Double.class)); // Retrieve it as a Double
    }

    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T) map.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to throw a `ClassCastException` but it runs through successfully printing:

```
Test: value
```

Why doesn't it throw?

Comment: What does the `System.out.println` call print?

Comment: I have a feeling it's linked to the same reason of why you cannot pass a primitive type for a generic type argument. Have you tried changing the values in the `Map` from `Object` to something else, such as `String`? Maybe it's allowed due to the polymorphic property of `Object`

Comment: @mariosangiorgio : It prints `Test: value`.

Comment: Interestingly, `test.get("test", Double.class).doubleValue()` _does_ throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh same result with `Map<String, String>`

Comment: Why would you expect a `ClassCastException` when the compiler clearly warns you that the cast is **unchecked**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932090/java-generics-with-class-t I have a feeling the `Class<T> clazz` is not doing what you think

Comment: @Sebas: Well, it's not doing *anything* -- it's not used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is instructive to consider what the class looks like after removing type parameters (*type erasure*):

```
public class Test {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    public static void main (String ... args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.put("test", "value");
        System.out.println("Test: " + test.get("test", Double.class));
    }

    public Object get(String key, Class clazz) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

This compiles and produces the same result that you see.

The tricky part is this line:

```
System.out.println("Test: " + test.get("test", Double.class));
```

If you had done this:

```
Double foo = test.get("test", Double.class);
```

then after type erasure the compiler would have inserted a cast (because after type erasure `test.get()` returns `Object`):

```
Double foo = (Double)test.get("test", Double.class);
```

So analogously, the compiler could have inserted a cast in the above line too, like this:

```
System.out.println("Test: " + (Double)test.get("test", Double.class));
```

However, it doesn't insert a cast, because the cast is not necessary for it to compile and behave correctly, since string concatenation (`+`) works on all objects the same way; it only needs to know the type is `Object`, not a specific subclass. Therefore, the compiler can omit an unnecessary cast and it does in this case.

Answer (score 17):

That's because you are casting to the generic type `T`, which is erased at runtime, like all Java generics. So what actually happens at runtime, is that you are casting to `Object` and not to `Double`.

Note that, for example, if `T` was defined as `<T extends Number>`, you would be casting to `Number` (but still not to `Double`).

If you want to do some runtime type checking, you need to use the actual parameter `clazz` (which is available at runtime), and not the generic type `T` (which is erased). For instance, you could do something like:

```
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: This could just be the one line `return clazz.cast(map.get(key));`

Comment: You're right - I guess I should have checked the Javadoc, since it's not the sort of thing I commonly have to deal with. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, Cyäegha: note that both differ a bit by how they handle `null`. `class.cast(null)` works without problems, while `null.getClass()` throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: True, I guess that's another good reason to use `Class.cast` here, since `HashMap.get` can return `null`.

Answer (score 8):

I found a difference in the byte code when a method is called on the returned "Double" and when no method is called.

For example, if you were to call `doubleValue()` (or even `getClass()`) on the returned "Double", then the `ClassCastException` occurs.  Using `javap -c Test`, I get the following bytecode:

```
34: ldc           #15                 // class java/lang/Double
36: invokevirtual #16 // Method get (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
39: checkcast     #15                 // class java/lang/Double
42: invokevirtual #17                 // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
45: invokevirtual #18 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(D)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
```

The `checkcast` operation must be throwing the `ClassCastException`.  Also, in the implicit `StringBuilder`, `append(double)` would have been called.

Without a call to `doubleValue()` (or `getClass()`):

```
34: ldc           #15                 // class java/lang/Double
36: invokevirtual #16 // Method get:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
39: invokevirtual #17 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
```

There is no `checkcast` operation, and `append(Object)` is called on the implicit `StringBuilder`, because after type erasure, `T` is just `Object` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You do not get a `ClassCastException` because the context in which you are returning the value from the map does not require the compiler to perform a check at this point as it is equivalent to assigning the value to a variable of type `Object` (See [rgettman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813010/577417)).

The call to:

```
test.get("test", Double.class);
```

is part of a string concatenation operation using the `+` operator. The object returned from your map is just being treat as if it is an `Object`. In order to display the returned 'object' as a `String` a call to the `toString()` method is required and since this is a method on `Object` no cast is required.

If you take the call to `test.get("test", Double.class);` outside of the context of the string concatenation you will see that it does't work i.e.

This does not compile:

```
// can't assign a Double to a variable of type String...
String val = test.get("test", Double.class);
```

But this does:

```
String val = test.get("test", Double.class).toString();
```

To put it another way, your code:

```
System.out.println("Test: " + test.get("test", Double.class));
```

is equivalent to:

```
Object obj = test.get("test", Double.class);   
System.out.println("Test: " + obj);
```

or:

```
Object obj = test.get("test", Double.class);
String value = obj.toString();    
System.out.println("Test: " + value);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Java is unable to process the cast with an inferred type, however if you use the `Class.cast` method, the call to get throws an exception as expected :

```
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(map.get(key)) ;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to explain that more thoroughly.

**Edit :** you might be interested by this [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).