# Java generics self-reference: is it safe?

Tags: java, generics, this, self-reference

I have this simple interface:

```
public interface Node<E extends Node<E>>
{
    public E getParent();

    public List<E> getChildren();

    default List<E> listNodes()
    {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // ------> is this always safe? <-----
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E root = (E) this;

        Queue<E> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        queue.add(root);

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            E node = queue.remove();

            result.add(node);

            queue.addAll(node.getChildren());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I see that `this` is always an instance of `Node<E>` (by definition).
But I can't imagine a case where `this` is not an instance of `E`... 
Since `E extends Node<E>`, shouldn't `Node<E>` also be equivalent to `E` by definition??

Can you give an example of an object that's an instance of `Node<E>`, but it's not an instance of `E`??

Meanwhile, my brain is melting...

---

The previous class was a simplified example.
To show *why* I need a self-bound, I'm adding a bit of complexity:

```
public interface Node<E extends Node<E, R>, R extends NodeRelation<E>>
{
    public List<R> getParents();

    public List<R> getChildren();

    default List<E> listDescendants()
    {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E root = (E) this;

        Queue<E> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        queue.add(root);

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            E node = queue.remove();

            result.add(node);

            node.getChildren()
                .stream()
                .map(NodeRelation::getChild)
                .forEach(queue::add);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public interface NodeRelation<E>
{
    public E getParent();

    public E getChild();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An easy example to illustrate the problem: a node of a different type of node:

```
class NodeA implements Node<NodeA> {
    ...
}
```

And:

```
class NodeB implements Node<NodeA> {
    ...
}
```

In this case, `E root = (E) this` would resolve to `NodeA root = (NodeA) this`, where `this` is a `NodeB`. And that's incompatible.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. I was going to post something similar, but then I tested it, and `E root = (E) this;` doesn't throw an exception. `E root = (E) this;` is not resolved to `NodeA root = (NodeA) this` due to type erasure. If I'm not mistaken, it can only be resolved to `Node root = (Node) this;` @MicheleMariotti

Comment: @Eran I think `ClassCastException` may happens when you iterate through result of 'listDescendants()'

Comment: @Eran I'm very curious to know why it's not failing at that point. I know for sure that the types are incompatible, but I have to find an accurate explanation of why the CCE is not thrown on that line (could be that Java is using Object for erasure, but I don't know). Will comment when I find an exact reason.

Comment: @ernest_k as @Eran said that cast will be resolved like `Node root = (Node) this`. I wrote a post based on your answer, that demonstrate a real problem. You may use my post to update your one after that I will delete mine.

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov It helps to see an example (actually) illustrating the failure, thanks for adding your answer

Comment: @Eran I saw that the bytecode didn't even have a cast instruction. So googling a little led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812940/5761558

Comment: @ernest_k I've just seen a bytecode, you were right about type erasure, 'E root = (E) this;' - actually that cast will be ignored by compiler. It casts objects only when generic is resolved by particular parameter, like when we are iterating a result list.

Answer (score 2):

Without `<E extends Node<E>>`, you could have either of these cases:

```
Node<Integer>
```

where the generic type isn't a `Node` at all, or

```
Node<DifferentNode>
```

where the generic bounds don't match.

That said, it's *not* typical to see a bound this way, as `Node<E>` is expected to be a node that *contains* some value of type `E`, and `children` would be a `List<Node<E>>`, not a `List<E>`.

Comment: I know it's *not typical*, but I have a complex case where self-bound is required. Please, see the update on the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, very weird to see "curiously recursive template pattern" used for a graph structure.

Comment: Not weird at all for something like `IComparable` in C# [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in `E root = (E) this`. It might work well until you start iterating through result of `listNodes()`.

That example demonstrates where exactly `ClassCastException` will be thrown:

```
public interface Node<E extends Node<E>> {

    List<E> getRelatedNodes();

    default List<E> getAllNodes() {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add((E) this); //<--that cast is not a problem because of type erasure
        return result;
    }
}

class NodeA implements Node<NodeA> {

    public NodeA() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<NodeA> getRelatedNodes() {
        return null;
    }
}

class NodeB implements Node<NodeA> {

    private List<NodeA> relatedNodes;

    public NodeB(List<NodeA> relatedNodes) {
        this.relatedNodes = relatedNodes;
    }

    @Override
    public List<NodeA> getRelatedNodes() {
        return relatedNodes;
    }
}
```

Execute:

```
List<NodeA> nodes = new NodeB(Arrays.asList(new NodeA())).getAllNodes(); //according to generic it is list of NodeA objects
for (NodeA node : nodes) { //ClassCastException will be thrown
    System.out.println(node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the punctualization. Indeed I was referring to general safeness, not limited to the single unchecked cast statement.

Answer (score 1):

With this sort of situation it is often useful to have a `getThis` method that (by convention) returns `this`.

I would do the following

```
public interface Node<E extends Node<E, R>,
                      R extends NodeRelation<E, R>>
{
    public List<R> getParents();
    public List<R> getChildren();
    public List<E> listDescendants() ;
}
public interface NodeRelation<E extends Node<E, R>,
                              R extends NodeRelation<E, R>>
{
    public E getParent();
    public E getChild();
}
abstract class ANode<E extends ANode<E,R>,
                     R extends ARelation<E,R>>
implements Node<E,R> {
    abstract protected E getThis() ;
    public List<E> listDescendants()
    {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
        E root = getThis() ;
        ...
        return result;
    }

}

abstract class ARelation<E extends ANode<E,R>,
                     R extends ARelation<E,R>>
implements NodeRelation<E,R> {
}

class CNode extends ANode<CNode, CRelation> {
    public CNode getThis() { return this ; }
    ...
}

class CRelation extends ARelation<CNode, CRelation> {
    ...
}
```

Although I might not bother with having both abstract class and interface layers.

Comment: Upvoted. Eventually, I ended up implementing the same thing :)